# Target Unreachable, 'empIqama' returned null

Tags: hibernate, jsf-2

i am getting an error target unreachable.my xhtml file and java file are below.

```
<h: inputText id = "iqamaType"
value = "#{manageEmployee.empIqama.aqamaType}"
styleClass = "input"
required = "true"
requiredMessage = "#{msg['iqamatype_msg']}"
style = "font-weight:bold" />
```

In the managed bean

```
public Tbl_aqama getEmpIqama() {
    return empIqama;
}

public void setEmpIqama(Tbl_aqama empIqama) {
    this.empIqama = empIqama;
}
```

Comment: how did u declared `empIqama` in `manageEmployee` class? do u mind to share Tbl_aqama class?

Comment: Your question is incomplete: 
Where is the stack trace and what component exactly is unreachable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following,
1) The bean manageEmployee is declared properly. Either through annotation (@ManagedBean) or using faces-config.xml.
2) Make sure the object empIqama is not null.

If this doesn't solve, please share some code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

JSF/EL does not set/create nested properties. Given this construct,

```
value="#{manageEmployee.empIqama.aqamaType}"
```

all EL basically does under the covers is:

```
manageEmployee.getEmpIqama().setAqamaType(input.getValue());
```

Look, it doesn't do a `setEmpIqama()` anywhere. You have to prepare it **yourself**. Your concrete problem is that `getEmpIqama()` returned `null` which makes the `setAqamaType()` call impossible. The error message is also telling exactly that.

The most sensible place to prepare it is the (post)constructor of a request/view scoped bean associated with the view, in this case the class behind the `#{manageEmployee}` bean:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    empIqama = new Tbl_aqama();
}
```

Please note that the setter is completely unnecessary in this construct. It's never been used by JSF/EL. You can safely remove it.